# Clojure Java Interop JavaClass.class

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am using a Java library that frequently references as method arguments `JavaClassName.class`.

For example, it will require a call:

`document.get(TextAnnotation.class)`

I have tried a few ways to reference the `TextAnnotation.class` in this method argument, including: `TextAnnotation$class` and `TextAnnotation.class` but I cannot seem to figure out the right way to call it in Clojure.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried the obvious thing, `(.get document TextAnnotation)`?

Comment: Have you tried just `(.get document TextAnnotation)` ? If you look at `(type String)` (e.g.) you'll see it's already an object of type `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: @jas. That is the correct solution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. I think it was too obvious and I overlooked the obvious. Thanks.